# While Loop doesn't stop executing

Tags: c

The "while" in my code doesn't stop running even when I type " ^Z "
it's supposed to stop since the EOF exists.
Any idea why?

```
 #define NUM_OF_GRADES 10
    int maxInArray();
    int main()
    {   char ch1;
        int grades[NUM_OF_GRADES];
        int grade;
        printf("Please enter a character:");
        printf("\n");
        scanf("%c",&ch1);
        printf("Please enter grades:");
        printf("\n");
        while (scanf("%d",&grade)!=EOF)
        {
           grades[grade-1]++;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `grades[grades]++` i think you can not increment an array like that

Comment: @Adam: why not?

Comment: well it's not the element she increment

Comment: @Yasmin12  Try Ctrl + d

Comment: It sure is dangerous, as it could easily be outside of the arrays bounds, when `grade` is not checked, but otherwise I don't see a problem there.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow already tried ,didn't work.

Comment: @Yasmin12 When do you want it to stop?

Comment: @Yasmin12  After Ctrl +z you should press Enter.

Comment: @narusin When I type  ^Z

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Still doesn't work

Comment: Are you pressing `Ctrl` Key and `Z` Key at the same time?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thank you!! worked:)

Comment: Fyi, this invokes undefined behavior regardless. `grades[];` contains *indeterminate* content. You're incrementing, sure, but you have no idea *what* you're incrementing *from*.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY what is the point that you made the user press `Ctrl` key and `Z` key at the same time?

Comment: @narusin It corresponds to EOF input on Windows.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes I noticed, this is missing : int grades[NUM_OF_GRADES]={0};

Comment: @Yasmin12 I think you should change `(scanf("%d",&grade)!=EOF)` to `((scanf("%d",&grade)) !=EOF)`.